# Is there any difference between the size of memory allocated for the following types of declaration:

Tags: c

i) `static int a, b, c;`

ii) `int a; int b; int c;`

I am not sure as to how will the memory be allocated for these types of declaration. And if these declarations are different then how much memory is allocated for each declaration?

Comment: Several good answers already discuss the "where" of the allocations, so I won't rehash that, and no need for another separate answer. But, I wanted to note, that the memory *used* by each `int` will be exactly the same, but it's entirely possible that alignment or other issues *might* dictate that the actual memory allocated to make room for those variables could be somewhat more than what is actually used for the variables.

Answer (score 6):

```
static int a,b,c;
```

will allocate three ints (probably 32bits each, or 4 bytes) in the DATA section of your program. They will always be there as long as your program runs.

```
int a; int b; int c;
```

will allocate three ints on the STACK. They will be gone when they go out of scope.

Comment: One caveat - the second case assumes they are declared inside of a function.  If they are declared globally, I think they will go in the DATA section as well.

Comment: To be strictly pedantic, few operating systems will put them in a data section. They will most likely go into bss. And if they are in a function, the non-static ones might not get any memory allocated to them at all if there are enough registers.

Comment: Thanks. This seems helpful :)

Comment: with keyword static variabile will be assigned 0

Comment: @Claudio Daffra a global variable, even without the specifier 'static' will be initialized at program start. C11 6.2.4.3.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between the *size* of memory for

```
static int a,b,c;
int a;int b;int c;
```

Differences occur in the *lifetime*, *location*, *scope* & *initialization*.

Lifetime: Were these were declare globally, both a,b,c sets would exist for the lifetime of the program.  Were they both in a function,  the static ones would exist for the program lifetime, but the other would exist only for the duration of the function.  Further, should the function be called recursively or re-entrant, multiple sets of the non-static a,b,c, would exists.

Location: A common, thought not required by C, is to have a DATA section and STACK section of memory.  Global variables tend to go in DATA as well as functional static ones.  The non-static version of a,b,c in a function would typically go on in STACK.

Scope: Simple view: Functionally declared variables (static or not) are scoped within the function.  Global variables declared static have file scope.  Global variables not declared static have the scope of the entire program.

Initialization: follows along the same track as lifetime.  Globally declared a,b,c, static or not, are both initialized at program start.  If a,b,c are in a function, only static ones are initialized (at program start).  Functional non-static a,b,c are not initialized.

Optimization may affect location, especially for the functional non-static a,b,c which could readily be saved in registers.  Optimization may also determine that the variable is not used and optimizing it out, thus taking 0 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The variables that are defined as static will allocated in data segment at compile time. The same is true for global variables even though they are not static. Non-static variables defined within a block are allocated on the stack when the block is entered at runtime and are deallocted when th block is exited.

The amount of memory allocated is implementation dependent. The standard requires that an int is large enough to hold a 16-bit (2 byte) valued, but is can be larger. Most compilers you are likely to use now adays use 32-bit ints.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that 2nd declaration is inside function, than As Bard and Nashant already said these will be allocated in different memory sections (OS and compilers dependent).

But though variable size will be of the same size, they CAN consume different amount of memory.  If function (from 2nd declaration) is called recursively for example, there will be multiple instances of variables from 2nd declaration.